WPF Linq Any query on TreeViewItem tag cast question
I have WPF TreeViewItems and I defined a custom object class for the Tag e.g. CustomTag with properties such as a Type, Name, Description.
I need to get all Items where the tag.Type = "test" so I defined the following Linq query:
if (!myNode.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().Any(item => item.Tag is CustomTag && 
(CustomTag)item.Tag.Type = "test")) { ...

Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn't like it and I can't work out a proper way to do it

"doesn't like it" - Please be more specific. If there is an exception, it always helps to show the exact message and a stack trace. It's probably just a typo.

I think it complains about this part (CustomTag)item.Tag.Type = "test" - because it tried to read Tag from object and because = is not a comparison.
You would need tell explicitly to do parsing first: ((CustomTag)item.Tag).Type == "test", but there is much nicer syntax you can use: pattern matching:
if (!myNode.Items
    .Cast<TreeViewItem>()
    .Any(item => item.Tag is CustomTag customTag && customTag.Type == "test"))

Or
if (!myNode.Items
    .Cast<TreeViewItem>()
    .Any(item => item.Tag is CustomTag { Type: "test" }))


There is even a nicer syntax: item.Tag is CustomTag { Type: "test" }.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes right thanks :)

We can push it even further and eliminate the LINQ Cast<>: if (!myNode.Items.Any(item => item is TreeViewItem { Tag: CustomTag { Type: "test" } })). An advantage of pattern matching is that you can use it a case label.

I found the same solution as I looked again at the issue. Thanks for the reply
